# How to find the deepest ul/ol with list items in a nested list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to clean up bulleted lists generated by another program which has created nested lists which are unnecessary. I need to remove them. Here are 2 examples...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
   <ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <ol>
              Prep Steps
              <li>Step 1</li>
              <li>Step 2</li>
              <li>Step 3</li>
            </ol>
            <ul>
              Other things to note
              <li>Another LI 1</li>
              <li>Another LI 2</li>
              <li>Another LI 3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to find the ul/ol with valid list item context (any text) and remove all the extraneous uls wrapped around them. To do this, I was trying to find the deepest ul that has list items. I tried a few selector like `$("ul:has(li)")`, but this returns all the parent uls also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $('ul,ol').not(':has(ul,ol)')
```

```js
$('ul,ol').not(':has(ul,ol)').each((index,list) => console.log(list));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>List Item 1</li>
          <li>List Item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <ol>
                <li>Another LI 1</li>
                <li>Another LI 2</li>
                <li>Another LI 3</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: this works and thanks a lot. After I posted the question and found another way to do it. I updated the question now with the code. Can you please comment on how it can be improved.

Comment: @SirajSamsudeen it's hard to tell from your updated code what your goal is. Please state clearly what you're trying to achieve and what your challenges are. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Now I have edited the question to go back to the original version for which your answer works perfectly. Will try to post another question on the next problem with more clear goal. Thanks for your guidance and patience.