# how to clean up the extra bullets in lists in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have the following html generated by a program. The program has wrapped up the
lists with extra lists and that leads to extra bullets being visible on the HTML
page. I am trying to clean up the lists so that only the valid list items stay
and the extraneous surrounding lists are removed.

I wrote the following code which works for list1 and list2, but does not work for list3 and list4.

```
$("body>ul, body>ol").each(
    function removeExtraneousLists(index, element) {
        $element = $(element);

        $leafList = $element.find("ul, ol").not(":has(ul,ol)");
        $element.html($leafList.html())

    }
)
```

I guess that the condition I am looking for is wrong. Visually inspecing the list gives me an idea of when a list has extra bullets, but I am not really able to figure out how to write the correct selectors for cleaning up list3 and 4.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .expected {
      background-color: palegoldenrod;
      border: dashed 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="list1">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <ol>
                <li>Currency 1</li>
                <li>Currency 2</li>
                <li>Currency 3</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <strong>Expected Output:</strong>
  <ol class="expected">
    <li>Currency 1</li>
    <li>Currency 2</li>
    <li>Currency 3</li>
  </ol>
  <hr />
  <ul id="list2">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>A “geographical segment”</li>
                <li>A “service segment”</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <strong>Expected Output:</strong>
  <ul class="expected">
    <li>A “geographical segment”</li>
    <li>A “service segment”</li>
  </ul>
  <hr />
  <ul id="list3">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  For every request for clearance :
                  <ul>
                    <li>Prereq1</li>
                    <li>PreReq2</li>
                    <li>PreReq3</li>
                    <li>
                      PreReq4 (<a href="#_bookmark83">Refer to this</a>)
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  For every request for approval:
                  <ul>
                    <li>Approval Prereq1</li>
                    <li>Approval Prereq2</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Date of the last approval; and</li>
                <li>Names and signatures of approval committee.</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <strong>Expected Output:</strong>
  <ul class="expected">
    <li>
      For every request for clearance :
      <ul>
        <li>Prereq1</li>
        <li>PreReq2</li>
        <li>PreReq3</li>
        <li>PreReq4 (<a href="#_bookmark83">Refer to this</a>)</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      For every request for approval:
      <ul>
        <li>Approval Prereq1</li>
        <li>Approval Prereq2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Date of the last approval; and</li>
    <li>Names and signatures of approval committee.</li>
  </ul>
  <hr />
  <p>In particular, when setting up a new block:</p>
  <ol id="list4">
    <li>
      the approver shall:
      <ul>
        <li>
          ensure compliance with
          <a href="#_bookmark73">Another List</a>;
        </li>
        <li>appoint a delegation;</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      the requester shall:
      <ul>
        <li>ensure that he makes a request;</li>
        <li>
          <a id="requester"></a>
          <a id="_bookmark133"></a>ensure that he submits the letter by hardcopy;
        </li>
        <li>
          assist the approver in regularly:
          <ul>
            <li>reviewing the current status of his request</li>
            <li>reviewing the weekly progress</li>
            <li>reviewing the final closure</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <strong>Expected Output:</strong>
  <p class="expected">Exactly the same list with no change</p>

  <hr />
</body>

</html>
```

The expected output for list 3 is:

FYI - this is a follow-up to my last question for which I got a helpful answer that helped me move forward.

[How to find the deepest ul/ol with list items in a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770965/how-to-find-the-deepest-ul-ol-with-list-items-in-a-nested-list)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the code that's creating the extra lists in the first place?

Comment: I don't have access to that program. I get the output and I have to work with it :(

Comment: what would be the desired output for each of these lists?

Comment: As an alternative, have you considered doing this in css, eg `ul,ol { list-style:none; padding-inline-start:0 }`

Comment: @Argee the desired output is the extra empty lists to be removed so that only genuine content stays. I know what is extra when I look at it, but I am unable to clearly come up with a generic criteria that would fit all the above examples :(

Comment: @freedomn-m, thanks for your alternative idea. However, when I tried it, it removes all the bullets and hence multi-level lists all get jammed up into one level - if you look at the sample code and the output, you would understand that this option would not work.

Comment: @Argee, thanks for your feedback. Now I have updated the code snippet to show the expected output clearly. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.html()` to get the elements' contents. That will just return the contents of the first list item, not all of them.

Use `.append()` to move the elements to the place where you want them, and `.remove()` to remove the extra elements.

```js
$("body>ul, body>ol").each(
  function removeExtraneousLists(index, element) {
    $element = $(element);
    $leafList = $element.find("ul, ol").not(":has(ul,ol)").find("li");
    $element.empty().append($leafList);
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="list1">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <ol>
                <li>Currency 1</li>
                <li>Currency 2</li>
                <li>Currency 3</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <hr />
  <ul id="list2">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>A “geographical segment”</li>
                <li>A “service segment”</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr />
  <ul id="list3">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  For every request for clearance :
                  <ul>
                    <li>Prereq1</li>
                    <li>PreReq2</li>
                    <li>PreReq3</li>
                    <li>
                      PreReq4 (<a href="#_bookmark83">Refer to this</a>)
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  For every request for approval:
                  <ul>
                    <li>Approval Prereq1</li>
                    <li>Approval Prereq2</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Date of the last approval; and</li>
                <li>Names and signatures of approval committee.</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr />
  <p>In particular, when setting up a new block:</p>
  <ol id="list4">
    <li>
      the approver shall:
      <ul>
        <li>
          ensure compliance with
          <a href="#_bookmark73">Another List</a>;
        </li>
        <li>appoint a delegation;</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      the requester shall:
      <ul>
        <li>ensure that he makes a request;</li>
        <li>
          <a id="requester"></a>
          <a id="_bookmark133"></a>ensure that he submits the letter by hardcopy;
        </li>
        <li>
          assist the approver in regularly:
          <ul>
            <li>reviewing the current status of his request</li>
            <li>reviewing the weekly progress</li>
            <li>reviewing the final closure</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <hr />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the tips on using append and remove. Will try them out. My current method of finding the leaf node produces wrong results. Hence you edit also has the same problem. Have you looked at the output vs the original lists - it takes away a number of elements. I don't know how to remove the empty parent lists which do not have any content.